# How to check if an ip-address is reachable in C for linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to build a code which given an ip-address just prints the finalresult reachable or not. I guess we have to use ping command but am not able to correctly implement it.

Comment: open up a terminal and type ping -help

Comment: "am not able to correctly implement it" is not an error description, and this isn't http://gimme-teh-codez.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that "reachability" on IP networks is kind of tricky to test for.

It's perfectly possible that a server machine is running any number of real services (www, ftp, whatever), but has been configured not to reply to pings since [some people do that](http://www.xnews.ro/docs/icmp-ping.htm).

If possible, it's better to just connect like the real service you want to check for.

Comment: +1 for the only real option - just try to connect with whatever HTTP/IRC//FTP/POP/SMTP whatever server.

Comment: the linked URL http://www.xnews.ro/docs/icmp-ping.htm is no more available.. So this answer does not qualify to be an accepted answer, does it?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port   = htons(65432);  // Could be anything
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.1", &sin.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error connecting 192.168.0.1: %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port   = htons(65432);  // Could be anything
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.9", &sin.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error connecting 192.168.0.9: %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

On my system it prints:

```
Error connecting 192.168.0.1: 111 (Connection refused)
Error connecting 192.168.0.9: 113 (No route to host)
```

On my network `192.168.0.1` is my own computer, `192.168.0.9` is an address that is not on the network.

As you can see you get two different errors depending on if an address can be reached (the first line of output) or not (the second line).

Comment: Where's your IPv6 support? :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Unfortunately I have no access to an IPv6 enabled computer at the moment, so cant really test it. But the result should be the same, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not really. The difference is that yours will not work with IPv6.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant the errors should be the same.

Comment: The same as what? You're confusing me.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: On my system I get the error code 146 for connection refused. But how do I check if the server is alive? I mean, any specific error code?

Comment: @NJMR If the connection is refused that means the other end is alive, but there is no one listening on the port. In other words, the computer is running and you can reach it through the network, but the server *program* you try to connect to is not running (or is running but listening on another port).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes sir, I got it. My question is I want to know whether the IP is alive or not. As you said, if it is replying then it is alive. But for what error codes I need to check? I am writing a function which will return bool depending upon the status of IP (If alive = true).

Comment: @NJMR The two main errors for being able to *reach* the destination computer are `ENETUNREACH` and `ETIMEDOUT`. See e.g. [the `connect` manual page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well you'd want to construct a pipe between ping and your program using popen()

(see e.g.: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html)

Then you need to parse the input appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use e.g. [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/popen.html) with the [ping](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_ping.htm) command.

Or use the [libping](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Libraries/libping-12052.shtml) library.

Or, assuming some HTTP server is running on the remote machine, issue a `HEAD` HTTP request thru [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Or code the low level system calls done by ping. Use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find them out.

<sup>P.S. some system calls require "root" privilege. This is why `/bin/ping` is setuid</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, you can use `popen()`.

But remember, `ping` isn't reliable, firewalls can block ICMP echo (which is used by ping) yet the host could be still reachable on specific ports.