# Call to Connect takes too much time

Tags: c, sockets, unix, ip

My task is to check wheter an IP is alive or not. So I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9499177/3747770) and modified the code as shown below...

```
int isServerAlive(const char* serverAdd)
{
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port   = htons(65432);  // Could be anything.
    inet_pton(AF_INET, serverAdd, &sin.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin)) == -1)
    {
        // The two main errors you get if the host is dead are ENETUNREACH and ETIMEDOUT.
        if (errno == ENETUNREACH || errno == ETIMEDOUT)
        {
            printf("Error connecting %s: %d (%s)\n",serverAdd, errno, strerror(errno));
            return FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

When I try to execute this code, connect call is taking too much time.

- Am I doing anything wrong here?
- Are there any other better ways to check if an IP is alive or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be firewall issue?

Comment: _**// Could be anything.**_ Not true. It depends on your platform, and on your server side socket configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection attempt times out, then the network stack will try again a few times. Waiting for a time out, and the retries unfortunately takes time.

There are basically two ways to solve it:

1. Use non-blocking sockets. Then the [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) call either returns with a valid connection. It it will return with an error and `errno` set to `EINPROGRESS`. As said in the `connect` manual page you can use e.g. [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to see if the socket is writeable to know the connection attempt is finished, and you can get the status.
2. The second solution is to use threads. Then the connection attempt can work in the background while your main thread does something else.

Comment: The server which I am testing is alive and the connect call is getting timedout. Even if I am using non-blocking sockets, it will still get timed out. Am i right?

Comment: @NJMR If the server is alive, but you can't reach it then yes it might be a firewall problem. Also if you use non-blocking sockets then if the connection times out you will get the same error as if you were using blocking sockets. You just have check the status and fetch the error differently. It's all explained [in the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html).

Comment: One more thing: All the servers which I have to test (Aliver or not) does support ping. Can I use ping command for the same purpose?

Comment: @NJMR With `ping` you can only check if the servers are reachable. If you have a specific server program you want to check if it's alive then `ping` is not enough.

Comment: Yes, I just want to know whether the server is alive or not. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I am able to ping the server from the command prompt. But with this program, connect() is giving "Connection timed out". What might be the problem?

Comment: @NJMR The `ping` command uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) which is a completely different protocol from TCP. Ping and a `connect` call are not synonymous.

Comment: Yes, got it. While testing, using connect() for one of the server, i was able to get the reply back. But for the other server, it is giving "Connection timed out" (Ping is working on this tho). The later might be blocking the TCP?

Answer (score 1):

In case that the you know the servers will response ping, you should definitely use **ping** to do the detect. Say your servers are behind a Proxy or NAT, which can easily defeat your SYN detect.

In the Linux environment, a ping detect mechanism should like this:

`system("ping xx.xx.xx.xx -c 3 -i 1 -W 3 -q > /tmp/ping-xx.xx.xx.xx.log &");`

After 6 seconds, you can open the file, and parse the ping results:

> 3 packets transmitted, 0 received, **100% packet loss**, time 2039ms

```
Note: 
              -c 3: only issue 3 ping packets
              -i 1: send packets at 1 second interval
              -W 3: wait response up to 3 seconds, so the total time should no more than 3 + 3 = 6 seconds
              -q: suppress no needed information.
```

Those ping arguments only server as example, and you should custom them according to your real environment.

Comment: I dont have the liberty to write to log and then parse the log. Can I do it in the same flow?

Comment: You can use popen/pclose instead.